# android DexClassLoader. I cannot get a method called

Tags: android, jar, dex, dexclassloader

- I am using DexClassLoader to load a jar file translated to DEX from Java jar, using the dx tool.
- The jar file is in: /storage/sdcard0/Download/br_applications/calculator.dx.jar
- I have permissions:
- My code is (+/-):

  ```
      String url_jar_path = "/storage/sdcard0/Download/br_applications/calculator.dx.jar";
      String         dex_dir = context.getDir("dex", 0).getAbsolutePath();
      ClassLoader    parent  = Cargar_jars.class.getClassLoader();
      dexclassloader = new DexClassLoader(url_jar_path, dex_dir, null, parent);
      main_class = "browserun.main.Mains";
      Class clase = dexclassloader.loadClass(main_class);
      Class[] arguments_array = new Class[1];
      arguments_array [0] = String [].class;
      Method method_main = clase.getMethod("main", arguments_array);
      String [] params_array = { "param_1" };
      Object[] arguments_main_array = new Object[1];
      arguments_main_array [0] = params_array;
      method_main.invoke (null, arguments_main_array);
      /* Here I got Exception: Method not found. */
  ```
- I have tried with .apk file. And the result is worst yet. I do not get load the class...
- I have tries with .aar file. And the result was bad.
- ¿May anybody give me a code working?
- I am using Android Studio, and I create the jar files using a fake apk applications with a module, which is the Java Jar. The I use the dx tool to create the dx.jar file: 
          dx --dex --output calculator.dx.jar calculator.jar
  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in logcat for any clues as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I made a change:

```
method_main.invoke (null, arguments_main_array[0]);
```

instead:

```
method_main.invoke (null, arguments_main_array);
```

I had something wrong in the code of the called method in the external jar.

If I use:

```
dex --dex --output <jar target> <jar origin>
```

I got a valid jar.

But the code called worked before and not now... And I cannot debug it... :(